# Autoscale app services environments which is connected to api gateway

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am planning to deploy two zonal ILB ASEs which will be further load balanced by application gateway also I want to implement the auto scaling too. So how to implement the autoscaling of the ASE which is load balanced by application gateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to deploy at least two ILB ASEs - one per zone. After that create and publish copies of your application onto each of the AZ deployed ASEs. You will additionally need to deploy a load balancing solution upstream of the AZ deployed ASEs so that traffic bound for an application is distributed across all instances of the ASEs.

This [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-autoscaling-zone-redundant) and [Autoscaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/app-service-environment-auto-scale#:%7E:text=Azure%20App%20Service%20environments%20support,budget%20and%20or%20load%20profile) should help

Comment: Actually I am looking for autoscaling also apart from the above solution. I want to have the zonal redundancy  as mentioned above but I also want to implement the auto scaling of the app service in case of the heavy traffic. How to achieve that ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/app-service-environment-auto-scale#:~:text=Azure%20App%20Service%20environments%20support,budget%20and%20or%20load%20profile.